Application of Cauchy integral formula / residue theorem for evaluation of real-valued integrals
I try to evaluate integrals of the form
\begin{equation}
I(x) = \int_{0}^{x}\frac{f(t)}{t^{2}}\,\mathrm{d}t
\end{equation}
with $f(t)$ being a differentiable and real-valued function of the real-valued variable $t$ satisfying $f(t)\geq 0$ for all $t$ (the function $f$ is not symmetric). Looking for a general solution for all possible functions $f(t)$ for which the integral converges, I came across the Cauchy integral formula and the residue theorem. Unfortunately, I am not so confident when it comes to complex integration.
What I understand after browsing related stack exchange posts and some books:

instead of functions of real variables consider functions of complex variables ($t \rightarrow z$ such that $f(t) \rightarrow f(z)$)
evaluate the respective integral on a closed contour $\Gamma$ in the complex plane

For simplicity (I guess this assumption needs further discussion) I assume that $f(z)$ is analytic in $\Gamma$. Hence, my problem translates to
\begin{equation}
\oint_{\Gamma}\frac{f(z)}{z^{2}}\,\mathrm{d}z
\end{equation}
Still, I need to define the contour, and here already the first problem appears. $\textbf{Q1}$: What is a suitable contour? Something like? 
As far as I understand the contour $\Gamma$ should contain the pole, else $\oint_{\Gamma}\frac{f(z)}{z^{2}}\,\mathrm{d}z = 0$.
According to the Cauchy integral formula
\begin{equation}
\frac{2\pi i}{n!}f^{(n)}(z_0)=\int_{\Gamma}\frac{f(z)}{(z-z_0)^{n+1}}\ \text{d}z\,,
\end{equation}
which can be split up into
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\int_{\Gamma}\frac{f(z)}{(z-z_0)^{n+1}}\ \text{d}z &= \int_{\epsilon}^{x}\frac{f(z)}{(z-z_0)^{n+1}}\ \text{d}z\\
&+ \int_{x}^{ix}\frac{f(z)}{(z-z_0)^{n+1}}\ \text{d}z + \int_{ix}^{i\epsilon}\frac{f(z)}{(z-z_0)^{n+1}}\ \text{d}z + \int_{i\epsilon}^{\epsilon}\frac{f(z)}{(z-z_0)^{n+1}}\ \text{d}z
\end{split}
\end{equation}
but ($\textbf{Q2}$) how do I apply the formula / how do I evaluate these integrals? And finally, I am interested in $I(x)$, but the result of the Cauchy integral formula will provide something complex-valued. ($\textbf{Q3}$): How to obtain a real-valued result as a function of $x$?
I am happy about any help. Thank you very much.

Don't you need some restrictions on $f(t)$, since the integral may diverge?

The problem with contour integration to evaluate $I(x)$ is that you would need to somehow show that the arcs from $x$ to $ix$ and $i\epsilon$ to $\epsilon$ evaluate to something nice, which would be quite difficult for a general $f$. The function $f$ also needs to have a zero of degree greater that $1$ at $t = 0$ ($f(t) = t^a\cdot h(t)$, for $a > 1$) for the integral to even converge.

Contour integration is more of an art than a science, so you’re probably better off opening a book on complex analysis and doing some practice problems than asking for a guide on here.

Will your $f(t)$ contain some pole along the imaginary axis such as $f(x)=\dfrac{1}{x^2+1}$ (I know $f$ is not symmetric, but you know you can find such function, just I didn't have any example), then your region may be inappropriate, I guess a semicircle may be better than a quarter? But yeah you should take a look of complex analysis by yourself.
